# Timeseries with mysql

Tags: mysql, time-series, grafana

I have a few data like below in mysql database:

[image]

I have a grafana system which is connected with this database as a source. What I need to build is a timeseries data with this table. I have tried something like below (based on some reference documents as I am new to this entirely), but it gives me an error "Error 1055: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and....".

```
SELECT 
 $__timeGroupAlias(date,1h,0),
 COUNT(distinct(id)) AS id,
 'result' as metric
 FROM db.table
 WHERE
    $__timeFilter(date)
    AND result = 'pass'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

This error is not my primary issue, but guidance on how to build a successful query for this by anyone who has experience with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to help you do something, if you don't describe what actually you want to get in result. But here is a general advice: start from mysql itself. Right now you have problems: `'result'` is a string containing word `result`. If you want column with this name (like in your where clause) remove quotes. Also this column has to be in group by.

Comment: After you have query that is working in mysql start adding Grafana's staff, like time grouping. And remember, since you have `group by` columns you add should be in group by clause (unless they are aggregations like `count`). Error you are getting is about that: your first field in select (what substitutes `$__timeGroupAlias`) should be in `group by`. Probably you need to replace `Date_format` with `$__timeGroupAlias`, but I'm not sure since it's unclear why you added `date_format` in the first place.

Comment: @markalex, thanks for the comment. I am trying to build a timeseries graph in grafana with the data I have in the table. Basically x axis will have the date and y axis should have the count

Comment: You can use numeric indexes, which refer to your select statement, so `GROUP BY 1,3`